# Onde consigo um segredo do cliente ao cadastrar um id OAuth no google console Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, google, google-play

Estou desenvolvendo um app em Xamarin e queria publicar na play store para teste interno, porém é necessario criar um cliente OAuth e é ai que tudo complica. Consegui cadastrar um só que nele só vem com o Id do Cliente e quando clico em Registar me da acesso negado. gostaria de saber como consigo esse segredo do cliente já que ele não esta sendo gerado.